# If I can just get Fleeting Ghost as a rogue at lvl 2, is there any point to taking Cunning Sneak?

Tags: dnd-4e, rogue, stealth

`Fleeting Ghost`, as an `At will` move action, I can move up to my speed and make a stealth check to hide, and I take no penalty to stealth check for the movement. 
`Fleeting Ghost` is a level 2 `Rogue` utility power.

`Cunning Sneak` is a class skill, I only don't take penalties for moving more than 2 squares, and -5 for running instead of -10. I can make a stealth check to hide if I end my turn more than 3 squares from where I started.

It seems like `Fleeting Ghost` is a "cheaper" way to get the same effect, except with less stipulations and a reduction from all penalties instead of just a few.

Is there really any reason to get `Cunning Sneak` over `Fleeting Ghost`?

Comment: Amusingly, I'm building a character now in chat where I just considered this decision. Excellent timing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes.**

`Fleeting Ghost` is an `At will` move action. The beauty of `Cunning Sneak` is that works whenever movement occurs. If you take `Cunning Sneak`, many of the `Rogue` encounter powers give you movement that will trigger. Moreover, you missed the most critical part: *"any concealment or cover"* instead of *"superior cover or total concealment."*

`Cunning Sneak` is in every way better, `Fleeting Ghost` is the half-arsed version for rogues who don't feel like being ubersneaky.

Comment: Ahhhh I hadn't realized those stipulations for hiding. Thank-you for the information, ser!